# Setting a PTE to point a different physical page - Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, paging, tlb

Is it possible to make a PTE point a different physical page?

Say I'm currently in Kernel mode in a context of some process A that currently has the address 400k mapped to physical page no. 5.
Can I make that address (400k) to be mapped to a physical page no. 6 ? (For example)
If so, how?

I tried using this API:

```
set_pte / clear_pte / mk_pte / pfn_to_page
```

but no luck so far.

EDIT:

Some code:

```c
static pte_t *walk_page_table(struct mm_struct *mm, size_t addr)
{
    pgd_t *pgd;
    pud_t *pud;
    pmd_t *pmd;
    pte_t *ptep;
    spinlock_t *ptl;
    struct vm_area_struct* vma = mm->mmap;

    pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
    if (pgd_none(*pgd) || unlikely(pgd_bad(*pgd)))
        return NULL;

    pud = pud_offset(pgd, addr);
    if (pud_none(*pud) || unlikely(pud_bad(*pud)))
        return NULL;

    pmd = pmd_offset(pud, addr);
    if (pmd_none(*pmd))
        return NULL;

    ptep = pte_offset_map(pmd, addr);

    return ptep;
}

bool change_pte(size_t address, size_t new_page_phys_address)
{
    pte_t *p = walk_page_table(current->mm, address);
    pte_t new_pte;

    if (!p)
        return false;

    new_pte = pfn_pte(new_page_phys_address >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                      PAGE_KERNEL_EXEC);
    set_pte(p, new_pte);
    __flush_tlb_one(address);

    return true;
}
```

Some test code:

```
  struct pt_regs* regs = task_pt_regs(current);
  hexDump("someData", regs->ip, some_size);
  void * newPage = kmalloc(PAGE_SIZE,GFP_KERNEL);
  memset(newPage,0,PAGE_SIZE);
  change_pte(regs->ip, virtual_to_physical(newPage));
  hexDump("post someData", regs->ip, some_size);
```

Comment: Please, be concrete, what does it mean "no luck", and what have you tried exactly (give a code snippet)

Comment: Added some code ;) thanks.

Comment: how do you test this code? What are your expectations?

Comment: I just print the page content before and after the change. It DOES change. But not to what I was expecting :( edit: I meant that I print the virtual address pointed content after the change

Comment: Please, give the code which tests change_pte

Comment: Edited with some test code. Let me know if the test is wrong.

Comment: What does the code dump? Add its output.

Comment: The output won't help you much I'm afraid. Looks like two completely different memory areas (Totally different hex characters)

Answer (score 0):

Let me share one suggestion with you. It seems that there is no evidence, that `kmalloc` will return page aligned address (i don't know for sure, but you can check it). Let me make an illustration:

```
   page1  page2      remapped uspace page
|    000|000   |        |   000|
|    000|000   |        |   000|
    ^                    ^
    |                    |
 newPage               reg->ip
```

Try to use get_free_page instead of kmalloc. If this wouldn't help, i will try to repeat your experiment.

Comment: Okay, tried that: I get zeroes after the call to change_pte (E.g. if the previous data was f5a6a7b0 then post change_pte the data is: 00000000. I must do something wrong.

Comment: I afraid i don't  understand. You have memset(newPage,0,PAGE_SIZE) page you map to reg->ip. Why data shouldn't be 0?

Comment: No, I do not anymore. It currently has some real data that I want it to point to. No longer zeroes.

Comment: update the test code in your post. Also have you tried to read your pte back or to get page back (f.e. using follow page)? this check may be suitable in your situation.

Comment: Yes, with success. The output post change (set_pte) remains the same if __flush_tlb_one is NOT used. Otherwise (__flush_tlb_one is used) the output is all zeroes.